# What is the group id of this group name?

Tags: command-line, groups

How to get the group ID GID giving the group name.

The output would be for example:

```
Group adm with GID=4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A hack for the needed: (still maybe there is much better answer)

```
awk -F\: '{print "Group " $1 " with GID=" $3}' /etc/group | grep "group-name"
```

Simpler version(Thanks to @A.B):

```
awk -F\: '/sudo/ {print "Group " $1 " with GID=" $3}' /etc/group
```

Example:

```
$ awk -F\: '{print "Group " $1 " with GID=" $3}' /etc/group | grep sudo 
Group sudo with GID=27
```

Comment: Try this: `awk -F\: '/sudo/ {print "Group " $1 " with GID=" $3}' /etc/group`

Comment: See [UUOC](http://catb.org/jargon/html/U/UUOC.html)

Answer (score 65):

Use the [`getent`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/getent.1) command for processing groups and user information, instead of manually reading `/etc/passwd`, `/etc/groups` etc. The system itself uses [`/etc/nsswitch.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/nsswitch.conf.5) to decide where it gets its information from, and settings in the files may be overridden by other sources. `getent` obeys this configuration. `getent` prints data, no matter the source, in the same format as the files, so you can then parse the output the same way you would parse `/etc/passwd`:

```
getent group sudo | awk -F: '{printf "Group %s with GID=%d\n", $1, $3}'
```

---

Note that, for a username, this much more easier. Use [`id`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/id.1):

```
$ id -u lightdm
105
```

Comment: Ok, `awk` is shorter than `perl` =)

Answer (score 41):

This can be simply done with `cut`:

```
$ cut -d: -f3 < <(getent group sudo)
27
```

`getent group sudo` will get the line regarding `sudo` group from `/etc/group` file :

```
$ getent group sudo
sudo:x:27:foobar
```

Then we can just take the third field delimited by `:`.

If you want the output string accordingly, use command substitution within `echo`:

```
$ echo "Group sudo with GID="$(cut -d: -f3 < <(getent group sudo))""
Group sudo with GID=27
```

Comment: Why the process substitution? What's wrong with `GID="$(getent group cdrom | cut -d: -f3)"`?

Comment: @kos I don't like running things in subshells unless is a must.....

Comment: Note, that this is Bash specific. Same result can be achieved with: `getent group root | cut --delimiter ':' --fields 3` (or use short args). Seems like this case does not really require process substitution.

Answer (score 0):

Using `perl` one-liner:

```
% perl -ne '@elements=(split /:/); printf "Group %s with GID=%s\n",$elements[0],$elements[2]' <<< $(getent group sudo)
Group sudo with GID=27
```

or shorter (and better)

```
% perl -F/:/ -ane 'printf "Group %s with GID=%s\n",$F[0],$F[2]' <<< $(getent group sudo)
Group sudo with GID=27
```

Comment: Pretty sure perl can do the splitting for you, I think the `-F` or `-l` option does that.